# Transforming Bessel's equation with change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Let bessel's equation be written as

$ z^2$$\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}$ + $z$$\frac{dw}{dz}$ + $(z^2 -p^2)w$ = $0$

and show that the change of variables defined by $z = ax^b$ and $w = yx^c$ (where a,b and c are constants) transforms it into

$ x^2$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ + $(2c+1)x\frac {dy}{dx}$ + $[a^2b^2(x)^{2b} + (c^2 - p^2b^2)]y$ = $0$

Write the general solution of this equation in terms of Bessels function.

I also don't understand why we use this transformation. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: I'm using it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3219641), for example.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are invited to chose $b$ and $c$ such that the constant $c^2 - p^2b^2$ is equal to $0$. In this way you obtain a simpler differential equation...

Comment: But how would you accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the solution of the FIRST equation can be written as c1*F(z)+c2*G(z), where c1, c2 are computed based on the boundary conditions and F, G are Bessel functions.

Therefore, any equation that follows the SECOND equation pattern can be tranformed into an equivalent first equation, and thus be easily solved.